# Access to database without installing any client/lib

Tags: linux, database, windows, oracle, virtual-machine

I am currently on a project where I have 2 VM (virtual machine), a Windows and Linux one.
I also have an Oracle database where I have a simple table called "Material".

On the 2 VM, I want to connect to my Oracle database without any client or libraries. The thing is I want to create a script which would run on the VM and can connect to my database and insert some datas to my table "Material" but I can't install anything on my VM (like the mysqlclient for exemple).

So is it possible to connect to a database without installing anything on my VM? Or perhaps can I access to an online client to send my SQL to my Oracle Database?

I know it's quite difficult to understand my problem so if you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: IIRC the *ODBC Driver for Oracle* is installed by default, see if its listed in odbcad32.exe.  If so you can probably use VBScript + ADODB to issue SQL Commands against a DSN. (Windows)

Comment: When you say "I can't install anything on my VM", are you referring to n/w issues or is it something else?